# Conditional where clause with IN operator does not work

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTasks  
(TaskId   int,  
   CompanyId      int,
   YearCol varchar(50),
   MonthCol varchar(50),
   SomeValue varchar(50)
  );  
GO  

INSERT INTO #MyTasks 
SELECT 220,1,2018,1,50553.32
UNION
SELECT 220,2,2018,2,222038.12

DECLARE @Param1 int = 1
DECLARE @Param2 int = 0
SELECT * FROM #MyTasks
WHERE
(@Param1 != 0 AND taskid in (select taskid from #mytasks where companyid = @param1) OR @Param1 = 0)
OR
(@Param2 != 0 AND taskid in (select taskid from #mytasks where companyid = @param2) OR @Param2 = 0) -- because of this condition, all rows are being returned
```

How to return all rows from #MyTasks table if @Param1 was not passed to stored procedure? I'm initially setting it to 0 and want to use where clause only if was passed and is diffrent from 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just need to use some parentheses on the where clause and add a `OR` condition.

```
WHERE
(@Param1 != 0 AND taskid in (select taskid from #mytasks where companyid = @Param1))
or @Param1 = 0 --usually this would be IS NULL
```

This can be further simplified as

```
WHERE companyid = @Param1 or @Param1 = 0
```

Or with multiple parameters...

```
WHERE 
    (companyid = @Param1 or @Param1 = 0)
    and
    (someColumn = @newParam or @newParam = 0)
```

Comment: How to achive the same if I have two parameters? Your answer is correct, it started work when I added parentheses.
First parameter sliced result to ~4k rows, but second parameter is set to 0 and causes returning all rows again.

Comment: You'd need to wrap the first block above in parentheses, and then your second group of logic in parentheses.

Comment: Could you provide full example? I will edit my post within few minutes to help you write it

Comment: That's it. Thank you very much, I see u replaced or operator with and but totally don't understand why, it seems to be a bit confusing.

Comment: well the AND is needed if you want both of the conditions to be true. If not, use OR

Answer (score 0):

If you work on same table please doesn’t use not or in use just where clause it’s just too not read full table two times .

It’s can be done by :

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTasks  
(TaskId   int,  
   CompanyId      int,
   YearCol varchar(50),
   MonthCol varchar(50),
   SomeValue varchar(50)
  );  
GO  

INSERT INTO #MyTasks 
SELECT 220,1,2018,1,50553.32
UNION
SELECT 220,2,2018,2,222038.12

DECLARE @Param1 int = 0
SELECT * FROM #MyTasks
WHERE @param1 = 0 or companyid = @param1
```